# SSD is not recognized anywhere

Tags: windows-10, ssd

The SSD drive had windows 10 and everything worked fine until I decided to reinstall Windows 10 from a bootable USB. I booted the PC with a USB Windows installer plugged in and progressed to the step where you choose a drive to install to, but the list of drives was empty and windows installer showed an error that drivers for the drive were not found.

I checked bios - SSD not detected; tried to list disk in cmd prompt - no disks.

What might be the problem? SSD never showed any signs of problems before.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to test drives is always to first just disconnect them and reconnect them. In a laptop this can be more challenging as you have to do some disassembly, but in a desktop it is usually quite easy to do.

Sometimes it is just a loose cable, the timing is a coincidence - so always check the cheap and easy thing first, just unplug the drive's 1-2 cables and plug them back in. If it is a desktop you can also try different cables. If your computer has multiple slots for hooking up a drive, try those as well, just incase the connector on the computer side has gone bad.

If that doesn't work, the second thing to do is pull the drive and try it in another computer. If it doesn't show up there, its probably just a dead drive, bad luck - little to nothing can be done to fix a dead drive that won't even show up as connected, short of spending hundreds of thousands of USD on a drive recovery service. If you don't have access to another compatible computer try a "USB external drive enclosure", and then hook it up to your computer via USB. If you search around you can usually get them for under $20, and maybe even under $10 if you don't know someone you can borrow one from.

If none of these steps work, I've never had a drive I could save that was this far gone, and I'd suggest you declare your drive to be dead and unrecoverable. If any of the above steps work, then the drive itself is not (yet) dead, but it narrows down the problem to a connector, cable, or the computer's connectors, and you should be able to figure out which and go from there.

As a final note, SSD's unfortunately tend not to give any warning before they stop working, they just suddenly fail. Older spinning-platter hard drives would sometimes make funny noises and thus warn you that you need to act fast as time is running out, but often times they died suddenly too. Its just the nature of computer hardware that for most components their life is binary - on it works, or off it doesn't.